# Deny "change permissions" for CREATOR OWNER

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-permissions, user-permissions, ntfs

Using Windows Server 2008 version R2 Standard / Service Pack 1.

I have a shared folder containing the home folders of users. This is called user$.

I have the following share permissions on user$: Everyone: Read/modify

I have the following file permissions on user$:

**CREATOR OWNER**: Deny: Change permissions and take ownership: Subfolders and files only.

**CREATOR OWNER**: Allow: Everything except take ownership and change permissions: Subfolders and files only

**SYSTEM**: Full control: This folder, subfolders and files.

**BUILTIN\Administrators**: Full control: This folder, subfolders and files

**Domain Users**: Allow: Traverse, list, read, read attributes, read permissions, create folders: This folder only

I have applied this to the user$ share and replaced all child permissions with inheritable entries. So why do users still have permission to change permissions? *Take ownership* is not allowed and seems to work as expected.

The reason I need to do this is because something (still unknown) is changing the permissions in a way that makes the files inaccessible to users and messing up a lot of processes. This seems to happen randomly on a daily basis to about 5-10% of users.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Owner has an implict Read and Change permission access and has precedence over Deny permissions.

Check the effective access rights of an user to the file.

I suggest you enable Permission change auditing and see what is causing the issue.